# WS POST generates 405 error, but works in Postman

Tags: web-services, post, jax-rs, postman

Running locally against Tomcat 9, my GET endpoints are working fine, but any POST attempt generates a 405 error.  So I tried to simplify the request down to the following to eliminate the possibility of downstream code/processing somehow generating the 405 problem

```
@POST
@Path("/form")
public Response addUser(
        @FormParam("name") String name,
        @FormParam("age") int age) {

    return Response.status(200)
            .entity("addUser is called, name : " + name + ", age : " + age)
            .build();

}
```

The corresponding URL I am trying:

```
http://localhost:8080/rest/committee/form?name=joe&age=27
```

Works as expected in both Postman and the Intellij WS/Rest testing tool.  However, whenever I run it directly in the browser I get a 405 error.  As is the case so often with me, I think I'm missing something really fundamental.  Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try that URL in your webbrowser directly it will per default use GET not POST. As a result the server will reject the call.

if you want you browser to send a post call, you'll have to create a html form that posts the data to the service.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I had a feeling I was missing the forrest for the trees on some level!